# Using the evaluated case statement inside block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement

If I have the following switch statement:

```
case number
when 10, 11, 12
  do something
when 19, 20, 21
  do something
end
```

And `number` is 19, is there a way to use the compared against value inside the block when it's been evaluated? I.e. in the `do something` block of `when 19, 20, 21`, is there a way to grab whichever value matched `number` and sent it into the block?

Comment: You don't really need to know whichever value matched number in this case, since you already know what `number` is equal to.  Do you know what i mean?  This question would make more sense if you were matching against a regex, and you wanted to know which regex matched `number`, or against a range, and wanted to know which range matched `number`.

Comment: Sometimes a question is muddied by saying too much. Here it is your reference to `19` (and to a lessor extent, to the two references to nonexistent blocks). Considering your selected answer, your question would have been clear had you merely said, "In `do something` for `19, 20, 21`, is there a way to grab whichever value matched `number`?

Comment: You should fix your tags.  This question has nothing to do with Rails, so remove the Rails tag.  "switch-statement" means something in some languages, but not in Ruby, so remove it (my suggestion) or change it to "case statement". Keep in mind that some readers use tags to filter out questions. Your question will not be seen, for example, by anyone who excludes questions having a Rails' tag.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean doing this?

```
def do_something(num)
  puts num
end

case number
when 10, 11, 12
  #do some other thing
when 19, 20, 21
  do_something(number)
end
```

Or maybe directly without using any method:

```
case number
when 10, 11, 12
  #do some other thing
when 19, 20, 21
  puts "matched value is #{number}"
end
```